# How to Set a Default Date in J-Query UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to set a default date in my 2 textbox controls when the page loads.  I want always to set as the default the first textbox(StartDate) to be the first of previous month like 01/01/2013.  Also I want to set the 2nd textbox(EndDate) to be the end of previous month like 01/31/2013.  I would like to have these defaults loaded on the textbox once the page loads the first time.   Thanks in advance for your help.
Here is my current code:

```
     <link href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="FusionCharts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker();

            });
    </script>

<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox> 
</div>

<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start <input type="text" id="StartDate"/><br>
End <input type="text" id="EndDate"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#StartDate").datepicker();
  $("#EndDate").datepicker();
  var startdate=new Date();
  startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
  $("#StartDate").datepicker("setDate",startdate);
  var endDate=new Date(); // current date
  endDate.setDate(1); // going to 1st of the month
  endDate.setHours(-1);
  $("#EndDate").datepicker("setDate",endDate);    
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/Rf8rx/)

Your Code (Edited)

```
<link href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FusionCharts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#StartDate").datepicker();
       $("#EndDate").datepicker();
       var startdate=new Date();
       startdate.setMonth(startdate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
       $("#StartDate").datepicker("setDate",startdate);
       var endDate=new Date(); // current date
       endDate.setDate(1); // going to 1st of the month
       endDate.setHours(-1);
       $("#EndDate").datepicker("setDate",endDate);
    });
</script>

<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" Width="110px">   </asp:TextBox> 
</div>

<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" Width="110px">  </asp:TextBox> 
</div>
```

Note: In order for the above script to run, make sure that `ClientIDMode` is set to `static`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" ...
```

[jsfiddle for jquery 1.8.3 and jquery ui 1.8.23](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/Rf8rx/1/)

Comment: thanks, i am little bit confused about where to put this: Start <input type="text" id="StartDate"/><br>
End <input type="text" id="EndDate"/>.  I already have textbox set up in my aspx file as you can see in my first post.  thanks

Comment: thanks ZedBee, so now the StartDate field is populated but the EndDate field is blank and i am getting this error: "Line: 1608
Error: '$.ui.ie6' is null or not an object"

Comment: i have tried in chrome and i am not getting the error but still only the StartDate field is populated and the date-picker does not show up when i click either of the textbox.  I am using j-query 1.83 so could it be the problem?  thanks for your help

Comment: @moe check updated answer. In second fiddle, you can see the jQuery version has no effect on the code.

Comment: @moe random guess.. did you remove '$('.datepicker').datepicker();' from your code.

Comment: i have checked jsfidle to see if the version matter and it seems it matters.  The date-picker seems to work when i select 1.9.2 but it does not work when i select 1.8.3

Comment: @moe make sure you have checked jquery ui as well in jsfiddle

Comment: @moe I tested the code in visual studio, its working.you are including multiple versions of jquery in your page, may be thats causing the problem. Try to test the code with only one copy of jquery and jquery ui script.

Comment: it seems the problem is with the j-query script i am using.  i have downloaded jquery ui 1.10 and i am not getting the error i was getting and also it is populating both fields but the problem is when i click the text box i get this error: "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: i finally fixed i only needed to have these 2 j-queries:  <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.  Thank you so much for all your help.  You rock.............

Comment: :) gud to hear to fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
var firstDay, lastDay;
firstDay = firstDayNextMonth(new Date(2013, 0, 5)); // january = 0
lastDay = lastDayNextMonth(firstDay);
$("#StartDate").datepicker("setDate",  firstDay);
$( "#EndDate" ).datepicker("setDate", lastDay );

function firstDayNextMonth(date) {
    var d = date;
    if(d === undefined)
        d = new Date();

    d.setDate(1);
    if(d.getMonth() < 11)
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    else
        d.setMonth(0);
    return d;
}

function lastDayNextMonth(myDate) {
    var endDate = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), 1);
    if(endDate.getMonth() < 11)
        endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);
    else
        endDate.setMonth(0);
    return new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), 0);
}
```

[Link to the code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDQag/)

Comment: thanks for your response but the textbox are not prepopulated and also when i click the textbox, my datepicker is not working.. not sure what is going on

Comment: Check if the ID of the elements is really StartDate and EndDate after the html is generated. The code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xDQag/